# How to store composer(satis) package in git repo?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, satis

I have private list of repositories. I do not want to add to composer.json whole list in `repositories` into every package.

Composer ["said"](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md), that I have to create repositry with Satis. But I need to start web-server or open separate ssh access for it. But I do not want it. I already have git server with properly configured access.

Satis generate plain html and json files.

How to store those files inside another git repository and use it while installing or updating packages?

Comment: I'd imagine you'd just use the [*vcs* repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) with your own repo's URL. That doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Phil, i have repository that called "framework". Now i need to move some separate parts of it to another repository. So now i need to update composer.json of all apllications uses "framework" because composer [do not look to "framework" repositry list](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that a sub-repo may solve your issue.  In this way you could "link" the other repositories into the one specified.

http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Alternately could use create separate packages as described here?

[how to develop another sub-module along with the main application. [composer,php]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671144/how-to-develop-another-sub-module-along-with-the-main-application-composer-php)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible as you need to use Satis to update the package list with new versions of packages. Nor do I think it was the intent of Satis.

Satis is there to give you a single repository to add to each project which acts as a master. But it needs to be able to update itself with webhooks, cronjobs, or a manual command. If its not 'running' somewhere it won't be able to do this.

What you're asking for is a generic composer.json file stored in a repository that holds the list of required packages. You can then close this single file into each project.